# Magento 2.2 - adding name field to newsletter module

Tags: magento, module, custom-fields, newsletter

I'm using magento 2.2 and I want to add name field for newsletter module, so there has to be input box in front-end, and also it needs to show in backend, how to achieve this? There is a lot of posts about this, but they all are on older magento versions. So can someone explain how to achieve this?